# Does Firestore support automatic functions for updates?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Collection called Schedules and inside each of them there is an array called "times" with long numbers simbolizing the date (for example: 1908152300 simbolizes 2019, 15 August 23:00) and so on. Does Firestore support automatic functions that could delete the instance of "times" that passes the current time/date? Or is there a way to do it automatically without calling the removals manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in support for deleting expired documents (typically referred to as time-to-live or ttl).

I typically run such processes on Cloud Functions, with a scheduled functions and the Admin SDK. An example for the Realtime Database can be found [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-old-child-nodes), and it should be fairly straightforward to create something equivalent for Firestore.

Comment: I'm seeing the "delete-unused-accounts-cron" which deletes *daily* unused account. This sounds close to removing expired documents but I'm don't understand so much js also it needs to be replaced for Firestore.. sounds very confusing and I think I'll keep working on the impossible here